# No logs getting getting logged in log file for gremlin server

Tags: docker, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

This query is regarding the logs that I am not able to get while the janusgraph server start up inside a docker container.
Details below:
I am upgrading janusgraph version - 1.0.0-rc2 from an older version. Trying to deploy the server inside a docker container. Inside the docker file, I have used the base image of openjdk:11 and have provided,
`"CMD  "bin/janusgraph-server.sh" "start" "<location_of_conf.yaml>" "`.
The above command in the Dockerfile does not start the pod successfully. It runs into CrashBackLoopOff error with no other details.

Whereas, on correcting the same CMD in Dockerfile to:

`CMD "bin/janusgraph-server.sh" "start" && tail -f logs/janusgraph.log"`, server starts up successfully, but logs are not getting logged inside log/janusgraph.log file.

Need the log file to monitor the connections from the service and check the failures.

Tried connecting from the service and getting ClosedChannelException. I am unable to monitor the root because I don't have the logs.